# js or-equal operator equivalent as in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

In Ruby, I can do the following:

```
very_long_dictionary_name = {}
very_long_key_name = "a"

# this code usually will run inside a function invoked twice,
# first with parameter "b" and after with parameter "c", so
# I don't know if very_long_dictionary_name[very_long_key_name]
# was initialized, inside the function
(very_long_dictionary_name[very_long_key_name] ||= []).push("b")
(very_long_dictionary_name[very_long_key_name] ||= []).push("c")

very_long_dictionary_name    #=> {"a" => ["b", "c"]}
```

I tried it in Javascript and I got syntax error at `||=`. Is there a way to set the `very_long_dictionary_name[very_long_key_name]` as an empty array in javascript *only if it is undefined*, without repeating that long name?

Comment: `if (!very_long_dictionary_name[very_long_key_name]) very_long_dictionary_name[very_long_key_name] = [];`

Comment: There isn't. You have to do it in `the_very_long_way`: `(very_long_dictionary_name[very_long_key_name] || (very_long_dictionary_name[very_long_key_name] = [])).push("b")` which has the same effect as ruby's `||=`.

Comment: @Acidic: Almost but you might want to play with an object like `{a: undefined, b: null, c: false, d: 0, e: ''}` first.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I know that, but in my case I don't know "c" in advance (there can be a lot of code before pushing "c").

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set the
>   `very_long_dictionary_name[very_long_key_name]` as an empty array in
>   javascript only if it is undefined, without repeating that long name?

Not in JavaScript. There are a few shorthand if statements you could use to set the object key as an empty array, but all require you to write the object + key at least twice for what you are attempting to do.

In JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so you may use an 'alias' for your object key to neaten your code a little without having to worry about efficiency in this case.

```
let myRef = very_long_dictionary_name // Reference variable,
                                         changes with the object.
```

Comment: The reference bit won't work if it's `undefined`. We don't know if it's gonna be `undefined` or not so the whole reference thing is redundant.

Comment: In my case `very_long_dictionary_name` is granted to be an object; what can be `undefined` is certain non-existent key.

Answer (score 0):

I can do the job if I add a helper method to my `very_long_dictionary_name` object, what needs to be made only once.

```
var very_long_dictionary_name = {}
var very_long_key_name = "a"

very_long_dictionary_name.push = function(key, value) {
  if (!this.hasOwnProperty(key)) this[key] = []
  this[key].push(value)
}

very_long_dictionary_name.push(very_long_key_name, "b")
very_long_dictionary_name.push(very_long_key_name, "c")

return JSON.stringify(very_long_dictionary_name)
// {"a":["b","c"]}
```

No repetition of `very_long_dictionary_name` nor `very_long_key_name` in the same instruction.

Furthermore, I must be sure that the helper method name won't conflict with some possible future key.